# How to align two <div> tags horizontally in the same line inside a main <div> tag?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use two `<div>` elements inside a main `<div>`. But the problem is, in the first `<div>` I am using an `<image>` control and along with it I am fetching some text data from the database. And in second `<div>` I am using a `<gridview>`. But I am unable to show these two `<div>` elements in same line horizontally.

I have tried doing this:

```
<div style="width:1000px;overflow:hidden; height:auto; float:left; text-align:justify; margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="right part" runat="server" style="width:auto; float:left; margin:0 12px 12px 0;">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="122px" Width="148px" /><% =details %></div>
    <div id="left part" runat="server" style="float:left;width:auto;display:inline-block;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeader="False" 
                      ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" EnableModelValidation="True" 
                      onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
        </asp:GridView>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest me if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Try changing the width:auto to width:50%;

Comment: set __float:right;__ to the second __div__

Answer (score 10, accepted):

css

> display:inline-block

add div  *right part* and *left part* css

Answer (score 4):

Set 'right part' div **float** to **right**. Please check, you are using space in id selectors which is not right.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to get right and left justified text on the same line.

## CSS

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="textbox">
  <p class="alignleft">Text on the left.</p>
  <p class="alignright">Text on the right.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code *should align the divs in one line*... [**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9a3tH/5/)

`width:auto; float:left;` will only take the content width as div width, so *it will* always be inline as long as the total **width < 1000px**.

A simpler suggestion would be to use percentage for widths, this way you don't need to `inline` display the.

Also, idv `#` and `.` do not contan names with space, they are supposed to be one single word (*notice the change i made to your id names*)

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9a3tH/2/)

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#main {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    text-align:justify;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#right_part {
    width:49%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#left_part {
    border:1px solid #000;
    float:left;
    width:49%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hi @NoobEditor,
Yes that is why I am confused about this issue.Actually there is one more problem, I am keeping the Image and the details which I am fetching from DB in one div and the gridview is in 2nd div. But in most of the cases the details which I am fetching doesn't display on the page. whereas gridview is displayed.

Comment: Width of the main div is 1000px, and I have kept these two div's inside the parent div. I guess now the problem is with the width of the two div's.I have also tried width=auto; option, but in that case alignment of these two div's get's effected.

Comment: if the number of width is fixed( *if they are only 2*), then assign `width:500px` to both the child divs, that would help them, see here jsfiddle.net/9a3tH/6/  ...also it not `width=auto` but `width:auto`

Comment: @user2862233 : as for your image and data...m not mch of asp guy...you have to check 1st if the data is coming on the page or not...look through the page source and see if required data is there or not!